# Python console inventory stock manager using dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I’m new to Python (only 3 days). What I want to accomplish is a simple console stock inventory manager, after reading the official documentation and looking at examples, I realize the best way is using a dictionary. I need to do operation with the items in the stock, for example:

```
    # items

def addItem():
    items={}
    again="y"
    while again=="y":
        code=input("Input the code:")
        item=input("Input the Item:")
        items[code]=(item)
        again=input("Do you want to add another item [y/n]?")
    return items

def delItem(items):
    code=input("Input the item's code:")
    if code in items:
        del (items[code])

def getItems(items):
    print("List of all items:")
    for code in items:
        print(code,items[code][0:])


# operations

def addOperation():
    operations={}
    again="y"
    consecutive=0
    while again=="y":
        consecutive=consecutive+1
        date=input("Input the date dd/mm/yy:")
        in_or_out=input("Input the operation:")
        item=input("Input the item:")
        amount=int(input("Input the amount:"))
        operations[consecutive]=(date,in_or_out,item,amount)
        again=input("Do you want to add another operation[y/n]?")
    return operations

def delOperation(operations):
    consecutive=int(input("Input the operation's consecutive number:"))
    if consecutive in operations:
        del (operations[consecutive])

def getOperations(operations):
    print("View all operations:")
    for consecutive in operations:
        print(consecutive,operations[consecutive][0:])
        

# stock

from collections import Counter

def getStock(operations):

        stock = Counter()

        for date, in_or_out, item, amount, code in operations.values():
            if in_or_out == "input":
                stock[(item, code)] += amount
            else:
                stock[(item, code)] -= amount

        print("Code", "Item", "amount", sep="\t")

        for (item, code), amount in stock.items():
            print(item, amount, sep="\t")
```

Now, I'm trying to list the stock of every product on the inventory using the next formula: Stock (I) = input operation(i) – output operation(i).
By now I realize I have the values in two given dictionaries:

```
 items={
    bre:('bread'),
    cooking oil:('oil')
    }

    operations={
    1:('21/01/20', 'input', 'bread', 100),
    2:('12/04/20', 'output', 'bread', 20),
    3:('12/04/20', 'output', 'bread', 10),
    4:('30/10/20', 'input', 'cooking oil', 50),
    5:('01/05/20', 'output', 'cooking oil', 10)
    }
```

Basically, what I’m trying to accomplish is to print this:

Code Item Amount
bre  bread 70
oil  Cooking oil 40

Comment: Your code has a SyntaxError: You can't use the keyword `continue` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collections.Counter` is made for things like this:

```
from collections import Counter

inventory = Counter()

for date, in_or_out, item, amount, code in operations.values():
    if in_or_out == "input":
        inventory[(item, code)] += amount
    else:
        inventory[(item, code)] -= amount

print("Code", "Item", "Stock", sep="\t")

for (item, code), amount in inventory.items():
    print(code, item, amount, sep="\t")
```

Comment: Its works, but I didn’t realize that I have two dictionaries, the first one “items” had the value “code” do I need to print on the stock operations.

Comment: @RosellAlemanySaavedra I'm afraid I don't follow. You can edit your question to correct your input data.

Comment: Your updated code is invalid syntax, again. Before posting code here, please chwck that it runs.